# ImageView+ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

**Есть:** `ImageView` и сразу же под ним `ScrollView` с текстом.

**Цель:** сделать так, чтобы `ImageView` занимал примерно 50% любого экрана.

**Пробовал:** `layout_weight` сделать 50% - у `ImageView` и 50% - у `ScrollView`.
Получается теперь, что размер картинки зависит от размера содержимого `ScrollView`.

**Вопрос:** Как сделать так, чтобы половину экрана занимала картинка независимо от содержимого `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 2):

Надо для `ImageView` и `ScrollView` поставить значение `weight` равное 1.

Т.е. разметка должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы использовал параметр `layout_weight`. Прочти [этот](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/38-urok-7-layout-parametry-dlja-view-elementov.html) урок,

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).